# Rebuild SQL database through command line in swift

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite, pipe, command-line-arguments

Having a very difficult time trying to run command line arguments through Swift.  I need to run commands on SQL files that a user manually drags onto the app (so the file path is different every time).

The piping between my app and the command line is working (sending 'pwd' will return the correct response), but when I try sending the arguments I want I cannot get them to work.  I have tried using both "bin/bash" and "usr/bin/env" to no avail.

Essentially I am trying to rebuild a database that has been corrupted, without having to go in through terminal and do it myself.  Common errors I see across attempts include 'Launch path not accessible' or 'File or directory not found'.  I have tried using 'chmod 6' through terminal to set the permissions on the file, but this still does not work.  Any help on what I am doing wrong to access the file, or another way to try and rebuild a database, would be greatly appreciated.

```
    func checkForCorruption(filePath: URL) -> (String?, Bool){
    let folder = filePath.deletingLastPathComponent()

    let arguments = ["cd \(folder.relativePath)", "sqlite3 Restaurant.sql", ".mode insert",".output dump.sql",".dump", ".exit"]
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "bin/bash/"

    task.arguments = arguments

    let inPipe = Pipe()
    task.standardInput = inPipe
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe

    let errPipe = Pipe()
    task.standardError = errPipe
    var output : [String] = []

    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let errData = errPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if let out = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
        print(out)
    }
    if let errOut = NSString(data: errData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
        print("error: \(errOut)")
    }
    let outHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading

    if var string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
        output = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        do {
            try string.write(toFile: "\(folder.relativePath)/dump.sql", atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        catch _ {

            print("something went wrong")
        }
    }

    outHandle.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
        print("reading")
        if let line = String(data: pipe.availableData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            print("New ouput: \(line)")
        } else {
            print("Error decoding data: \(pipe.availableData)")
        }
    }
    return ("", false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some help at work, for anyone struggling with this, here is the answer (the print statement is just were the dump file is located).

```
let arguments = ["\(filePath.relativePath)", ".mode insert",".output dump.sql",".dump", ".exit"]
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/sqlite3"
    print(FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
```